# Compiling C++ files when including cmath in header

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, cmath

I have recently installed gcc from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/ and while everything else works fine whenever I try to include cmath in the header it is showing the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/5.0.0/include-fixed/math.h:273:5: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction: 4
     return __inline_isfinitef(__x) && __builtin_fabsf(__x) >= __FLT_MIN__;
     ^

/usr/local/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/5.0.0/include-fixed/math.h:273:5: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6
g++: internal compiler error: Abort trap: 6 (program cc1plus)
Abort trap: 6
```

I'm using OSX Yosemite and on typing gcc -v it shows the following:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0/5.0.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Configured with: ../gcc-5-20140928/configure --enable-languages=c++,fortran
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.0.0 20140928 (experimental) (GCC)
```

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Try using `g++` command to compile instead of `gcc`

Comment: @JGrice: It's plain to see from the output in the question that he _did_ use `g++`.

Comment: @Piotr S. No, I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Presumably your question is "how can I resolve this problem?" I think you should ask the distributor from whom you obtained GCC, because this is clearly an unexpected implementation bug... unless you installed the wrong version for your platform.

Comment: @JGrice while compiling i was using g++

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My mistake, saw he said `gcc -v` to test it and assumed you where compiling it with that

Comment: You don't seem to be alone : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63262 - no resolution there though, except for the suggestion to try a newer version of gcc.

Comment: Or, go with a stable gcc version, rather than the latest experimental version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when the GMP library was compiled for CPU which provides instructions not available on the runtime CPU, see [gmp CPU identification](https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-discuss/2003-April/000440.html)